# Html parameter passed to @Messages gets escaped in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, twirl

I'd like to pass a HTML text as a parameter to a message in a Twirl template, but when the template gets rendered the HTML gets escaped. For example, if my `messages` file has:

```
my.message=Click {0} to proceed
```

and my `template.scala.html` has

```
<p>@Messages("my.message", Html("<a href="/">here</a>"))</p>
```

when I open the page in a browser the `<a href="/"here</a>` part gets escaped, hence I don't have a clickable link. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move your usage of `Html` to the outside, or keep it in both places.

```
@Html(Messages("my.message", "<a href=\"/\">here</a>"))
```

The problem is that the inner `Html` gets converted to a `String` when passed into `Messages`. Then the templates compiler sees that `Messages` returns a `String`, so it escapes it. Adding another `Html` on the outside will prevent that.